# How can I setup Fiddler to make multiple requests at once?

Tags: fiddler

I have the following requests in my fiddler scratchpad and would like to know how I can send all of them at once?

I just do a spot check of our servers during fire fights to see response code and response times.

```
GET http://xx.xx.xxx.123/api/1/getit?what=this HTTP/1.1
Host: xx.xx.xxx.123
User-Agent: Fiddler
accept: text/xml

GET http://xx.xx.xxx.321/api/1/getit?what=this HTTP/1.1
Host: xx.xx.xxx.321
User-Agent: Fiddler
accept: text/xml

o o o
```

What I really hoped would be feature in scratch pad in fiddler is to highlight multiple requests and it would send them out simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the scratchpad, save a SAZ file containing the desired requests. When you want to play them back, load the SAZ file, Select All, and hit either the **R** or **V** keys.

(Learn more about the new Verify feature here: http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/blog/eric-lawrence/13-02-08/announcing-fiddler-2-4-3-beta.aspx)

Comment: this is an old post that I'm hi-jacking but I have since moved over to the mac/java world of development.  are there plans to build an MVP of fiddler for the mac as what is provided per windows?  I understand, that you can use mono and the beta but it is very buggy and slow.  I'm just used to the amazing (.net) fiddler for windows.  nothing and I mean nothing comes close to fiddler in the mac/**ix world.  Any info would be super appreciated.

Comment: @JaJ: Investigations into Fiddler for Mac are ongoing, and a new Mono build is due soon. Your best bet for the moment is a Linux or Windows VM: http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/14-01-15/running-fiddler-in-virtualbox-on-mac